# How to you prove that the Heat Kernel of the Sub-Laplacian is given by this formula?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, laplace-method

I been trying to show that the two integrals are equal but to no avail ,is my approach correct,I been looking at numerous literature and still could not see how those 2 integrals are equal,is one integral an approximation of another or are they equal? I been using hyperbolic functions identities all day and am truly stuck

I been looking at the papers
1)
B Gaveau,Principle de Moindre action,propagation de la chaleur,et estimees sous,elliptiques sur certains groupes nilpotents
2)
A Hulanicki,The Distribution of energy in the Brownian motion in the Guassian Field and analytic hypoellipticity of certain subellitpic operators

Here is my question,please see 2 images attached
[The Explicit formula for the Heat kernel of the Sub Laplacian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBINn.jpg)

and
[Another Explicit formula for the Heat kernel of the Sub Laplacian which i need to prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wloQe.jpg)

Comment: I just want to know if my approach is correct or not,are the two integrals equal or are they approximations of each other?

Comment: It'd be nice to have the equations in the post ([formatted](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)) instead of as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they're equal.  You make the change of variables $\tau' = \tau \rho$ in the $K_\rho$ integral.  You get one $1/\rho$ factor from the $\tau = \tau' / \rho$ in the denominator, and the other from $d\tau = d\tau' / \rho$.  No hyperbolic identities needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem thanks to @Nate Eldrege comment and looking at the paper for a more general case of the question in the paper titled **Semiclassical Limits of Heat Laplacians on h-heisenberg groups**(https://www.mmnp-journal.org/articles/mmnp/pdf/2013/01/mmnp201381p132.pdf)
Here is my attempt at the question, thank you again for the help
[image]

I was just wondering how would you evaluate the integral explicitly,I have already been using Wolfram Alpha and to no avail?